# Magento - Different price style on grid and product info

Tags: css, magento, php, magento-1.5

I'm trying to change the styles of the price on the different pages. In the product grid it's in the 'standard' look, but on the product info page I would like to show it bigger.
I figured out that the price is called in view.phtml with this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

The `product_type_data` is in the file default.phtml (template/catalogue/product/view/). Here I see:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

The `getPriceHtml()` again is in the price.phtml.

The style is in the CSS:

```
.special-price .price { font-size:18px; color:#990000; font-weight:bold; }
```

Is it possible to create a separate css-rule (eg `.special-price .price-large`) and how to apply it only to the productview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for something that is unique to product grids and use that. There is no need to change the HTML as well.

```
.products-grid .special-price .price { font-size:20px; }
```